# JSON Schema - validate schema on root if property in another subschema contains a fix value

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator, python-jsonschema

I would like to validate the following json:

```
{
  "endpoints": [
    {
      "ip_name": "plantuml_ip",
      "ip": "172.18.0.2",
      "ports": [
        {
          "name": "plantuml_port",
          "port": 8080,
          "proto": "HTTPS_TERM"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "subdomains": [
    {
      "name": "plantuml_port",
      "value": "plantuml"
    }
  ]
}
```

If `proto` contains value `HTTPS_TERM`, then `subdomains` with the same `name` should exists (`plantuml_port`). Here is an another valid example:

**Valid:**

```
{
    "endpoints": [{
        "ip_name": "plantuml_ip",
        "ip": "172.18.0.2",
        "ports": [{
            "name": "plantuml_port",
            "port": 8080,
            "proto": "HTTPS_TERM"
        }, {
            "name": "random_port",
            "port": 8181,
            "proto": "HTTPS_TERM"
        }, {
            "name": "no_subdomain",
            "port": 999,
            "proto": "NO_SUBDOMAIN"
        }]
    }],
    "subdomains": [{
        "name": "plantuml_port",
        "value": "plantuml"
    }, {
        "name": "random_port",
        "value": "random"
    }]
}
```

It is something like this possible? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is highly unlikely to be doable with json schema.